# How do I edit contacts from the front end in Joomla 1.5x?

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla, joomla1.5

I'd have thought this would be a native feature (seeing as joomla allows you to connect contacts with user accounts) but we can't find any way to do this!

Does anyone know of any extensions/modules that would allow this?

I'm not so hot on PHP so i'd really love to not have to code this by hand!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where exactly do you want to edit the contacts? In the user end? Why? You can edit them in the admin end!

Comment: Because I want users to be responsible for their own contacts!

Comment: From what I can see, it doesn't seem that Joomla can support this out of the box. Very frustrating -- of course there should be an option for users to be able to edit their contact details, otherwise they have to notify an admin whenever their details change.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but since it is still opened maybe you haven't found a solution yet. I faced the same problem myself and I think having the ability to manage contacts from the frontend is an essential feature for Joomla! to become more usable as a simple webapp creation tool.

Anyway, there are a couple of extensions that might help you out. However, both are commercial and don't support Joomla! 1.6. Here they are:

1. [Front-edit address book](http://b-elektro.no/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=19%3afront-edit-address-book-for-joomla-15x&catid=6%3aextentions&Itemid=8): simple
   interface. Note, however, that there
   might be a security issue with
   it. Google "front-edit address book exploits" and you shall find it (sorry, stackoverflow lets me post a max of 2 links per thread since I'm a new user). I emailed the developer and he assured me that the problem was already fixed, though.
2. [Grumpy contacts](http://grumpyengineering.com/purchase/grumpycontacts): on the demo site (there's a link at the page I pointed you to), it looked a little messy to my taste. In the Joomla! Extensions Directory, however, it has good reviews.

I never used any of those since all my projects are already migrated to Joomla! 1.6.

If you found another alternative in the meantime or even developed something yourself, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try in the user menu?
Another option would be install Community Builder.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Contacts in Joomla are handled by the builtin `com_contacts` compoment which provides basic functionality for adding contacts and some basic info **from the back-end**.

[**QContacts**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-details/4811) is a wonderful extension which gives you some more control over the data you can provide, but still no front-end support.

Unfortunately I am tackling this issue as well and it turns out there are no real out-of-the-box options for supporting front-end editing of contact details.